# ColdFusion Serialize Client Variables

Tags: json, coldfusion

Im looking to convert session to client variables so that I can migrate to a clustered environment.

I'm wondering if there is any clever way of doing this. I figured I could write some standard routine that has a setter / getter that you always use to set / get client variables. Ideally this method would just be available in every cfm / cfc.

I was thinking of having an application.Client object that would do this and do something like

application.Client.set('name', variable)

then

application.Client.get('name', variable)

The serialization would happen in there. Before heading down that path, has anyone done something similar, is serialising the data different depending on type ie Stuct vs Array vs Query etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be tough, because as stated in one of your earlier questions, the CLIENT scope cannot fully emulate the SESSION scope, for the simple fact that it can only include simple vars. You can't store a Structure in CLIENT for example.

But, one of those simple variable types is a string.

So, theoretically, if one were to have a way to serialize a complex data structure into a string, it could work.

Fortunately, you have a mechanism to do that: `<CFWDDX>`

```
<cfset data = StructNew() />
<cfset data.name = "Dale" />
<cfset data.type = "CF Programmer" />

<cfwddx action="cfml2wddx" input="#data#" output="serial" />

<cfset CLIENT.data = serial />
```

If you glance at your CLIENT.data var (serial) you'll see it looks something like:

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><struct><var name='TYPE'><string>CF Programmer</string></var><var name='NAME'><string>Dale</string></var></struct></data></wddxPacket>
```

Keep in mind that this isn't going to work for all solutions. You're not going to be able to serialize CFCs. Remember also that there is a size limitation on cookies (where CLIENT variables can be stored physically, in certain configurations) so you have a chance at losing data from very very large data structures.

You could wrap this serialization/de-serialization in a CFC that you house in the application scope, as you suggest above. The convenience here with `<CFWDDX>` is that it is a one-size-fits-all for Structures, Arrays, and all the other types as well.

Maybe not a very robust or long-term solution, but might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Of course, the cookie limitation can be avoided if they use database storage (and that's more likely, since it is more analogous to session storage and opens up less security risk).  Also, don't forget that you can serialize with JSON just as well as WDDX.

Answer (score 1):

The serializing itself should be the same regardless of the base object.  You could either serialize with JSON or with WDDX, but I'd go with JSON since that is less verbose.  You should note that you'll only be able to store serializable objects in the client scope - if your session scope had references to components, for example, those won't be able to be serialized and stored in the client scope.  Aside from that, your basic approach should work fine.

Comment: Yes I think I prefer JSON, im worried about the size of the DB.

Answer (score 0):

For one of my project I have use same kind of approach. Normally I was using client variable at every place of application so I had call client variable onRequest, deserialize it and stored in request variable to make it available.

hope this help.